# I am trying to click the first element from a list but the compiler throws exception every time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click the first element from the list.

I also tried type-casting the element before clicking but it is throwing an exception as well.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(ClientUICommon.getClientUIPaths().getProperty("BugFRList"))));
System.out.println("Bug to be clicked ");
ClientUICommon.sleep(3000);
((WebElement) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(ClientUICommon.getClientUIPaths().getProperty("BugFRList")))).click();
```

Comment: What does the exception says?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the below code:

```
((WebElement) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(ClientUICommon.getClientUIPaths().getProperty("BugFRList")))).click();
```

You see, the method `findElements` does not return `WebElement` object. It returns the List of WebElements. `List<WebElement>` to be exact.

What you basically did was clicking on the list, not it's element:

```
driver.findElements(...).click();
```

Which will throw compilation error, because `List<>` does not have method `click()`. In order to click on the first element of the list you should use `get` method with index argument like this:

```
list.get(0);
```

The above will return single `WebElement`

Full code:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(ClientUICommon.getClientUIPaths().getProperty("BugFRList"))));
WebElement firstElement = elementList.get(0);
firstElement.click();
```